# How to make 2 divs the same height, one image (without javascript)?

Tags: css, html

I want to make 2 responsive divs side by side, while keeping them the same height. One of them is an image, and the other div is a text. How would i make sure the image height equal, without using JavaScript. my image dimensions are 1000 × 1799.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#text {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

#image img {
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div id="text">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="lfc.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

whats happening is that if the try to make the height a percentage then it will obviously change to fit current screen settings but i want to make it responsive and same height.

thanks in advance!

Comment: `flex:1` is all you need on your inner divs in the box class

Comment: Not sure why using Java would be the answer here. *Maybe* JavaScript could help, but that's a completely different language.

Answer (score 1):

Your two columns actually are the same height already; you've just not allowed your image to expand to fill the `height` of the container. To allow this, simply set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on `#image img`. Be warned that in doing so you'll skew the image aspect ratio. If you want to maintain the ratio, you'll need to specify `width: auto` instead, though this will chop off parts of the image when there isn't room to display it all.

Note that you'll also want a `width` of `50%` on `#image`, so that both the text container and image container take up half of the `width`.

Also note that due to the nature of text taking up a different number of lines at different widths, it will always be a different height to the image. However, the container will always be the same height. I've added a background to the container to demonstrate this.

This can be seen in the following.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#text {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  background: cyan;
}

#image {
  width: 50%;
}

#image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div id="text">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */

  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}


<div class="row">
   <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
   <div class="col"><img src="lfc.png"></div>
</div>
```